# Ajax post data coming in wrong format . Django

Tags: python, jquery, post

Am using a script to make a simple post request to my Django backend. I want the data to be in Json format.

```
<input id ="my" type="submit" onclick="me()"/>

<script>
function me()
{
      var data2 =JSON.stringify ({
                      "crave": "romana",
                      "uid": "100",
                      "access_token": "AAA"                     
                  });
    alert(data2);
     $.ajax({
                      url: "http://localhost:8000/trial/",
                      type: 'POST',
                      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                      data: data2,
                      dataType: 'json',
                      processData: false
                  });

}
</script>
```

In the view when i print request.POST it shows the following

```
 {u'{"crave":"romana","uid":"100","access_token":"AAA"}': [u'']}
enter code here
```

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try without the "stringify"?

Comment: Yes , and the result of print request.POST is                                             <QueryDict: {u'[object Object]': [u'']}>

Comment: What about processData: true, and no stringify? Note that x-www-form-urlencoded is a format different than json, and jquery does the conversion from a javascript object to x-www-form-urlencoded, unless you stop it with 'processData: false'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/trial/',
  data: data2, // without stringifying
  success: function(res) { }
});
```

Or as a shortcut:

```
data2 = {crave: "romana", uid: "100", access_token: "AAA"}
$.post('http://localhost:8000/trial/', data2, function(res) { });
```

Comment: Perfect, I thought that the success function does not make any difference to the data being sent. What was I doing wrong?

Comment: @AkashDeshpande The success function doesn't make a difference... It was probably a combination of processData & contentType being set.